# How to verify if contain specific word before insert in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to verify if is inserting some word in my database mysql?
Exemple: I have a table called **subcategoria**, is it possible to verify before insert if contains the word **script** before sended?
How to do this in mysql database?
Anyone can help me?

I need to create a trigger with these quoted conditions.

Comment: So show what you have tried. What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I don't know how to start, someone can send a link to me?

Comment: Go through the links Sloan Thrasher mentioned (on how to post/explain the questions better). Apart from that using 'INSERT IGNORE' might help.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You need to do the research, and if you run into problems or get stuck, then ask a question. The links I provided above are really helpful.

Comment: Yeah this question contains no real details on what you've tried or how the problem looks with regards to **mysql** and **mysqli**. Add a query, some data samples of what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I only include this line: IF NEW.nome like '%script%' THEN

this worked for me, thanks for everybody.